# Colorcolumn above foldtext

Tags: vim

(In the terminal) I want to set the Folded highlight background color the same color than normal text, so folds don't standout the aggresive way they do by default. That's easy (`ctermbg=NONE` for Folded, `fillchars+=fold:\`), but then the fold "transparent" background is shown above the colorcolumn, as in the screenshot. I tried:

`highlight Folded cterm=NONE ctermbg=NONE`

`highlight clear Folded`

and

`highlight Folded NONE`

but to no avail. I'm not sure this is possible at all, at least in the terminal.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. Vim highlighting priorities are mostly hard coded in the source. There is nothing you can do about.

**Update** This has been fixed with 7.4.667

Comment: I'm glad to hear this has been fixed. Here's the patch for people who are interested in the solution: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/fbc25b20cbf29d6f9846e97875474f18e8d0c7be [answering my own question]